# The UI is locking on calling the long method on progress changed event of background thread

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I am using the background thread for doing some long time taking work. The progress changed event is returning the correct update and progress bar also working fine.
On progress changed event I am updating the progress bar. Also on progress change event I would like to update the animation. When the ShowLatestSimuationStep method takes near about more than 500ms time then the UI buttons are not working, not able to cancel the long work or minimize/maximize of parent form.

```
private void SolverWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _solverProgress.SetTitle(e.UserState.ToString());
            _solverProgress.SetProgress(e.ProgressPercentage);
             _layout.ShowLatestSimuationStep(fileCount);
            fileCount += 1;
        }
```

What will be the probable reason?
I checked other question related to this. These are related how to use BackGroundWorker.

Comment: Well, the `ShowLatestSimuationStep` method executes in the UI Thread, so whatever it does that takes time will be blocking. But you didn't say what this method is supposed to do. Is this about an *animation*? What animation? Isn't a ProgressBar enough? What are you animating that takes so much time? Can you do without it, or make something less demanding? It's not very useful to do work in a BackgroundWorker to then block the UI Thread again with something else.

Comment: This method is fetching file data and and showing the updated 3d model(stl). My current need is to show the updated model.

Comment: Maybe the *fetching* part needs to be performed in the BackgroundWorker as well. But the work in the BGW and the work in the UI must be *balanced*, otherwise you flood the UI with so much data that you're creating a blocking operation in any case. -- If you can make use the async/await pattern here, it's much simpler to balance the operations, since you can await a method that performs the background work, then update the UI then await again. Anyway, this depends on what you're doing, in practice, which is unknown.

Comment: @jdweng That's what the `ProgressChanged` method is there for: that's the handler of the event raised by `ReportProgress()`.

Comment: @Jimi : The report progress writes the updates and the updates get sent to another object.  The main thread should not be accessing the report progress method.  In the following example the main thread should be reading the property resultLabel.Text : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker

Comment: @jdweng I don't know what you're referring to. The `ReportProgress` method is called from the `DoWork` event. It raises the `ProgressChanged` event that the OP is handling using the standard handler. The value(s) of the progress (`e.UserState`) is of course read and used in the handler of the event, which is raised in the UI Thread. This is what the OP is already doing. -- The problem, here, is the time needed to updated the UI with the data received.

Comment: @Jimi : The _solverProgress.SetProgress() method shouldn't be updating the UI inside the background task.  It should be calling a separate UI event to update the interface.  The Progress Change should be like a timer event that when a certain amount of work is performed (or using a timer) the results of the backgroundworker is reported.  The reporting shouldn't slow down the background task for any significant amount ot time.

Comment: @jdweng That method, `_solverProgress.SetProgress()`, is not called from within the `DoWork` event handler (which is the part of code that executes in a worker Thread), it's called from the `ProgressChanged` event handler, which is executed in the UI Thread. There's no need to call anything else, because nothing would change: we're on the UI Thread already, everything is executed synchronously. In any case, it's the `_layout.ShowLatestSimuationStep()` method that takes time, here. The BGW, in the meanwhile, keeps going and reporting back. You cannot even BeginInvoke(), it's useless.

Comment: @Jimi : I disagree.  the code shown is part of a worker (SolverWorker_ProgressChanged) and should not be updating directly a User Interface that takes significant time to execute.   Any method inside a worker that takes time should be run a an async event.  You may need to use an Invoke to prevent cross-threading.

Comment: @jdweng C'mon, that handler, `SolverWorker_ProgressChanged`, is not *part of the BackgroundWorker*, it handles the event raised by ReportProgress. This event is raised in the UI Thread, there's no need to invoke anything here. If you mean that blocking the handler also blocks the BGW Thread, that *unfortunately* is not happening (it works as `Post()`, not `Send()`). It blocks the UI Thread instead.